# Delete duplicates in SQL query ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

**A)** suppose a table. that i want to perform a DELETE function on .
This is done in ms access 2003 sql query. **NOTE** There are many many many many entries. in the few hundred thousand ... to million ranges.so hopefully if there can be a code that deals well with a large dataset. there is 3 types of mood only.

```
 DayNumber   Mood
     1       Mad
     2       Sad
     2       Happy 
     2       Sad
     3       Sad 
     3       Happy
```

when there are a few moods in one day we only want to keep the most important one. 
so lets have a delete function delete for duplicates of days . first deleting the less important moods.   importance of moods is Happy>Mad>Sad. So I want:

```
 DayNumber   Mood
     1       Mad
     2       Happy
     3       Happy
```

**B)** I was first starting at easier without three options for mood jsut two . where Happy>Sad

```
 DayNumber   Mood
     1       Sad
     2       Sad
     2       Happy 
     3       Sad 
     3       Happy
```

Where I will Ideally get

```
 DayNumber   Mood
     1       Sad
     2       Happy 
     3       Happy
```

It doesnt matter whether you do the first example or secodn for me I'm stuck either way !

This is what i have for the second question so far.. btu it doesnt work cuz i have an aggregate function in the where clause .

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE (Mood='Sad') and (COUNT(DayNumber)=2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small & fixed number of moods, you can hardwire the hierarchy like so:

```
DELETE FROM Table a
WHERE
(a.Mood='Sad' 
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM Table b
   WHERE b.DayNumber = a.DayNumber
   AND b.Mood in ('Happy','Mad')))
OR
(a.Mood = 'Mad'
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM Table c
   WHERE c.DayNumber = a.DayNumber
   AND c.Mood = 'Happy')))
```

Comment: Thanks! i hadnt even had a clue before how to do the 3 moods !  jsut a random question. is it possible to have an ORDER BY in a DELETE ?  jsut if i want it ordered a certain way after the delete function runs thru so i dont have to make anotehr query jsut for ordering

Comment: Also what should i do if i have a very large number of entries. liek in the few hundred thousand range

Comment: No, the `DELETE` statement doesn't support `ORDER BY`.  You'll have to `SELECT` the rows you're interested in afterward, and only then can you use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: When you say "large number of entries" do you mean more than three moods?  If it's just a few more, you can add additional `OR` sections.

Comment: nope jsut three moods i mean there is a lotta data to go through and im not sure how slow this code will go if i have a dataset of a million or so

Comment: Good question!  The answer depends on a lot of factors, unfortunately.  A common way to improve query performance is to consider creating an index.  In this case I'd try creating an index that includes the `Mood` and `DayNumber` columns.  Unfortunately, Access doesn't give you a query analyzer that helps you make these sorts of decisions.  So it's a bit of a crap-shoot, I'm afraid.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Table where Mood='Sad' AND DayNumber IN (SELECT DayNumber FROM Table WHERE Mood = 'Happy')
```

Comment: Thank you this is simple and nice